# Creating a bar graph in Power BI for multiple response Forms question

Tags: powerbi-desktop

First Question:

So I have a Form with a bunch of survey questions and one of the questions is a choose all that apply. The resulting graph in Forms looks like this: [Forms Bar Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRZPh.png) in the Forms results dashboard.
Each one of those colored columns represents one of the choices in the list, so the graph displays the number of times each option was selected across all survey responses, make sense? Exactly what I want.

When I pull the question in BI, the graph looks like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpkza.png)

As you can see, BI wants to count the combination of answers, rather than the individual count of each option. Are you with me?

So, my question is…how do I set up the BI slide/report so it displays a normal bar graph like it appears in Forms, rather than collecting each response as all those options together as one?

I tried a bunch of different combinations using different visuals, options for axis and values, and it all comes out the same. A friend of mine and I actually even split the column into separate colums by choice but it does not organize the data by common response, it organizes each choice in the order it was selected from the form. There must be an easy way for BI to reproduce the graph from Forms and also be able to add a slicer to sort by grade level, etc.